# Derived a secondary formula to solve quadratics, does it have a name?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, quadratics

For any quadratic it can be challenging to look at it to factor a binomial representation, so I derived an equation, I am wondering if it has any special significance or if it has a name.

$$For:ax^2+bx+c$$
$$Let: b=d_1+d_2,\ where \ d_1\times d_2=ac \\$$
$$d_2=b-d_1$$
$$(b-d_1)(d_1)=ac$$

I got a secondary quadratic that is always much easier to solve than the first, where both roots are used in the first quadratic to complete the square. It seems very useful, since the derived version has no term preceding the square, and you can just look at these to solve them.

$$d^2-bd+ac$$

For example:

$$Given:10x^2+4x-6$$
$$d^2-4t-60$$
$$d^2-10t+6t-60$$
$$(d_1-10)(d_2+6)$$
$$d_1=10,\ d_2=-6\\$$

Then the problems become trivially easy to solve

$$10x^2+10x-6x-6$$
$$10x(x+1)-6(x+1)$$
$$(10x-6)(x+1)$$
$$x_1=\tfrac35,\ x_2=-1$$

Is there anything new here, or is this just something like a partial derivation of the quadratic equation?

Comment: You've effectively just substituted $x=-d/a$.

Comment: So I could just use $d^2+bd+ac$ the same way I guess without worrying about the negative sign

Comment: It's not new as it follows immediately from the Quadratic Formula,  which is ancient. But it's correct.

Comment: I guess I didn't realize the thing that defines a quadratic is basically knowing the product and sum of two variables

Answer (score 1):

This is the first method I learned for factoring quadratics (it's not very useful for solving quadratics if the roots aren't rational numbers). It doesn't seem to be in most standard textbooks, though. It's useful in a context where you're expecting the roots to be rational (because, as you say, the "derived" quadratic can be solved by guessing - you're just looking for two integers whose sum and product are two known integers).